# Calculate Bandwidth for Each Application (TCP/UDP) on Windows?

Tags: sockets, winapi, tcp, udp, bandwidth

Is it possible to calculate bandwidth of networking applications (TCP/UDP) by using Win32 API on Windows?

AFAIK TCP bandwidth calculation can be done by using [GetPerTcpConnectionEStats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb485738(v=vs.85).aspx)
function. But I could not find any function for UDP.

[PSPing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psping) seems to be working for UDP, therefore I assume that there must be a way to measure the bandwidth of UDP connections somewhere. Am I right?

Is there any other coding method to gather instant UDP bandwidth usage per connection on Windows?

Comment: UDP is connection-less, so there are no "per-connection" stats available for UDP, like with TCP. Look at functions like `GetUdpStatistics/Ex/2()`

Comment: You are right, my bad. I meant to write per port instead of per connection.

Comment: I don't know of any Windows API to get that info on a per-port basis.  You will probably have to use something like [winpcap](https://www.winpcap.org/) to manually monitor the network traffic directly.